# Can the transport layer (TCP, UDP...) recognize a fake MAC adresses?

Tags: macos, tcp, udp, ip, communication

Does anyone know if those protocols (even one of them) can recognize a fake MAC address, and if they can, how?

If you can provide source or example, it will be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. MAC addresses do not leave the local network. The receiver of a UDP datagram or TCP segment does not get to know the originating device's MAC address.

Comment: If the receiver does not know the originating device's MAC address then how does it knows who to send a respond to?

Comment: The transport layer responds by IP address. At the network layer the ARP protocol is used to map IP to MAC address before passing to the link layer to send. If the destination is local then the ARP mapping will be direct to the receiving station. If the destination is non-local then the mapping will be to the local gateway that will perform next-hop routing. ARP is a bit of a misfit protocol that straddles both link and network layers.

Comment: Thank you. another question that is related - do you know if the information in a socket is critical to execute the ARP protocol? I know that it contains the IP address it listens to, but I heard the information in the socket itself is not critical for the protocol... do you know the answer to that?

Comment: For outgoing packets the only information required to 'use' ARP is the IP address of the destination. If the mapping is not already cached then the sender sends a broadcast ARP message containing the destination IP address. Only the owner of that IP address responds with a reply containing its MAC address. The link layer can then construct a frame acceptable to the ethernet MAC.